# Цикл, принимающий данные в ардуино и сохраняющий в массив

Tags: python, arduino, serial, arduino-uno, pyserial

### Мне нужно передать 8 чисел в ардуино с помощью pyserial. Как принять эти числа и сохранить их в массив(циклом)?

Код снизу в ардуино принимает значение и циклично записывает это значение в массив. Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб цикл на питоне передавал ей числа, а она записывала бы их в массив.

---

Код python

```
# text_and_data_3 = ['11111111', '00000000', '11111111', '00000000', '11111111', '00000000', '11111111', '00000000']

for i in range(8):
    arduino.write(str(int(text_and_data_3[i], 2)).encode())
```

Код в ардуино:

```
// tu - массив, в который надо записать данные(byte)
// inc - переменная, в которую записывается число(int)

if (Serial.available() > 0) {
       inc = Serial.parseInt();
       if (inc != 0){
       for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        tu[i] = inc;}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
int i = 0;

while (Serial.available() > 0 && i < 8)
{
    inc = Serial.parseInt();
    if (inc != 0)
    {
         tu[i] = inc;
         ++i;
    }
}
```

При ваших условиях все передаваемые числа должны быть <= 255. Если нет, `tu` должен быть `int`.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо вам большое. Я немного отредактировала то, что вы отправили, и мне это помогло.
i объявляется в начале программы и равно 0.(не в лупе)

while (Serial.available() > 0 && i < 8)
{
    inc = Serial.parseInt();
         tu[i] = inc;
         ++i;
    if (i == 8){
   i = 0;}
}